# I accidentally ran sudo mv /* ../ - can I reverse the damage?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sudo

I'm a complete idiot when it comes to servers...

I was trying to move a directory up a level, because I had 
`/var/www/website.com/website.com` and I only needed to have `/var/www/website.com`

Well I was brilliant enough to run (on a live server with a running site of course)

```
sudo mv /* ../ (from /var/www/website.com/website.com)
```

I cancelled this pretty fast and it couldn't have run for more than a few seconds. Now I can no longer ssh into the server:

```
network error: software caused connection abort
ssh: Could not resolve hostname: Name or service not known
```

I know the server is still online because the website is still running as if nothing happened (using nginx, php, mysql). I can see errors generating from the forum software backend.

```
Error #0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I moved some files I never should have touched. My host provides a rescue system but I am afraid to reboot because those are the files I probably mucked during this.

I'd really like to not reboot and risk a very long downtime if this turns out to be catastrophic.

**EDIT:** I went into rescue mode, mounted the partitions, found the extra folders (`bin`, `boot`, `dev`, `etc`, `home`)that got moved, moved them back to `/root`, rebooted and am now getting a connection time out when trying to hit server. Wondering what to try next before attempting to move everything to another server.

Anyway I can clean or repair `/root` to find out what exactly got damaged?

Comment: I partially agree with JakeGould, but I think you could reinstall all installed packages as a bandaid if you absolutely must fix this install for some reason.  If you do, I'd recommend migrating services as soon as practical to a clean machine.

Comment: You might have started with a `cp` command to copy to a new or different folder [structure] to start with for a test first or something. This is a classic example of not testing a simple task beforehand. Practice makes perfect and a little pain helps you learn too!!

Comment: These are the moments when you are very glad you have kept good backups.

Comment: So you moved root to `/var/www/website.com/`  Presumably you have a load of stuff in this directory as well as another `website.com` directory.  But in your root, you would generally have `/etc /boot /dev /home /lib* /mnt /opt /root /sbin /usr`  If you see any of these, just move them back (note that the new location of `mv` might be `/var/www/website.com/bin/mv`

Comment: (this assumes that you can login and get a shell, all bets are off if not)

Comment: That's part of the problem right now.. I think I could get to those files if I mount the right partitions in rescue mode. Pretty sure /.boot got dragged along and who knows what else.

I normally would be in rescue mode already but I have a pretty active site l don't want to take offline for a few hours yet.

Comment: Boot the system normally, try to ssh in. If you don't get "connection refused", at least sshd is running, similar for the web server. Try a few times (to flush log buffers), reboot to rescue, look at the syslog and webserver logs to see what's missing. If you get absolutely no error or connection to any port (try connection to, e.g., port 50051, should refuse connections), it's not actually booting and you'll need console to see why.